# V-row and v-col are mis aligning after refreshing

Tags: vue.js, grid, window, resize, vuetify.js

I have made a row using v-row,v-col,the problem is that columns get misaligned when window is resized. I have to refresh the window to resize them again. Is there a flag or other way to keep them aligned on resize.
Please provide any instructions to solve this I provided the code here.

```
    <v-row  class="mx-2" v-if="!isResizing">
      <v-col>
        <v-card> <DoughnutChart :data="this.statusCountData" /></v-card>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <v-simple-table>
          <thead style="height: 20px; background-color: rgb(207, 228, 235)">
            <th class="col-md-auto">Orders</th>
            <th class="col-md-auto">Count</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr style="font-size: 14px">
              <td style="height: 25px">Ontime Delivered</td>
              <td>{{ this.ontimeCount }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 25px; font-size: 14px">
              <td>Delayed</td>
              <td>{{ this.delayedCount }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </v-simple-table>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <v-card><DoughnutChart :data="this.channelData" /></v-card>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <v-simple-table>
          <thead style="background-color: rgb(207, 228, 235)">
            <th class="col-md-auto">Channel</th>
            <th class="col-md-auto">Price</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr style="font-size: 14px" v-for="item in channels" :key="item._id" >
              <td style="height: 25px">{{ item.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.amount }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </v-simple-table>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

Comment: Please try to make working demo of your problem using the vuetify playgrond  https://play.vuetifyjs.com - including your code that sets the `isResizing` variable. It probably doesn't need to include your tables, chart etc.